# Alphanumerically sort a nested list of mixed data types in Python

Tags: python, sorting, nested-lists

Assuming I have the following nested list:

```
nestedlist = [[ 'ABC' ,  1.5   ,  2  ,  '8W'  ],
              [   2   , 'EXT'  , 5.8 ,  '2W'  ],
              [ 'DEF' ,   2    , 0.2 ,  '2Z'  ]]
```

for the sake of explaining my question I will refer to the inner lists as rows   (i.e nestedlist[0] = row1, nestedlist[1] = row2, etc...) and collectively the items from within the inner lists that share the same ordinal index as columns (i.e. nestedlist[0][0] = item1 of column1, nestedlist[1][0] = item2 of column1, etc...)

How would I sort the rows based on the values within a particular column such that if sorted on column1 the resulting structure would look like the following:

```
 nestedlist = [[   2   , 'EXT'  , 5.8 ,  '2W'  ],
               [ 'ABC' ,  1.5   ,  2  ,  '8W'  ],
               [ 'DEF' ,   2    , 0.2 ,  '2Z'  ]]
```

if sorted on column2 the structure would look like:

```
 nestedlist = [[ 'ABC' ,  1.5   ,  2  ,  '8W'  ],
               [ 'DEF' ,   2    , 0.2 ,  '2Z'  ],
               [   2   , 'EXT'  , 5.8 ,  '2W'  ]]
```

if sorted on column3 the structure would look like:

```
 nestedlist = [[ 'DEF' ,   2    , 0.2 ,  '2Z'  ],
               [ 'ABC' ,  1.5   ,  2  ,  '8W'  ],
               [   2   , 'EXT'  , 5.8 ,  '2W'  ]]
```

and lastly if sorted on column4 the structure would be:

```
 nestedlist = [[   2   , 'EXT'  , 5.8 ,  '2W'  ],
               [ 'DEF' ,   2    , 0.2 ,  '2Z'  ],
               [ 'ABC' ,  1.5   ,  2  ,  '8W'  ]]
```

I am aware that if all of the items within a column are of the same type than the sorted(nestedlist, key=itemgetter(sortColIndex)) function can be used but I cannot for the life of me figure out how to get this to work using mixed types.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python analog of natsort function (sort a list using a "natural order" algorithm)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2545532/python-analog-of-natsort-function-sort-a-list-using-a-natural-order-algorithm)

Comment: while similar in that both involve natural order sorting they differ in that my question is asking about naturally sorting a nested list of mixed data types while the link you provided discusses solution for naturally sorting a single list of strings.

Comment: Have you done any research into sorting nested lists by a certain column? That's a reasonably common task. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2828059/sorting-arrays-in-numpy-by-column), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22698687/how-to-sort-2d-array-numpy-ndarray-based-to-the-second-column-in-python), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6835531/sorting-a-python-array-recarray-by-column), and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/409370/sorting-and-grouping-nested-lists-in-python), in addition to the above comment about natural sort.

Comment: Convert everything to strings, then elements that are numbers back (not applicable if you have strings containing numbers and they should remain strings). Alternatively, use a comparison/key function that can handle all applicable types. Whether it's a nested list or plain doesn't matter, the question is about sorting, not handling nested lists (and those have been asked, too).

Comment: TigerhawkT3 ... thank you for providing links to 4 posts that do not address my question of how to sort nested lists of MIXED DATA TYPES. to answer your question as to whether I have looked into how to acomplish this myself I have and cannot find a solution that does not involve unpythonically converting all of the data in the orginal nested list into strings and performing  a natural sort on the now string data and then having to type check each and convert back each data item when I go to use it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you everyone for the comments and solutions you provided.
searching several of the links you provided and the subsequent links there within lead me to http://productarchitect.com/code/better-natural-sort.py which addresses all of the edge cases I was encountering. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

With the python for natural sort shamelessly copy-pasted:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
nestedlist = [[ 'ABC' ,  1.5   ,  2  ,  '8W'  ],
              [   2   , 'EXT'  , 5.8 ,  '2W'  ],
              [ 'DEF' ,   2    , 0.2 ,  '2Z'  ]]


import re
def natural_key(string_):
    """See http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001018.html"""
    return [int(s) if s.isdigit() else s for s in re.split(r'(\d+)', string_)]

sort_column = 0

print(sorted(nestedlist, key=lambda x: natural_key(str(x[sort_column]))))
```

If you don't care about natural sort just do `key=lambda x: str(x[i])`.  This solution converts any non-strings to strings before comparing.